# Infile statement in SAS

Tags: sas

Is there an option in the infile statement to skip the first n lines? I know in the import statement but is there an easy way in the infile statement?

```
data sub;
  length start end r $100 a$20 i n $1000;
  infile "blah.txt" lrecl = 50000 dsd delimiter = '09'x ;
  input start end r a i n
   ;
 run;
```

Comment: Don't forget, for delimited files `PROC IMPORT` just generates a datastep to read the file in, which is then available to look at in your log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the firstobs option:

```
%let n=2;
data sub;
  length start end r $100 a$20 i n $1000;
  infile "blah.txt" lrecl = 50000 dsd delimiter = '09'x firstobs=&n;
  input start end r a i n; 
 run;
```

alternatively, you can use conditional logic (more flexible but less efficient):

```
%let n=2;
data sub;
  length start end r $100 a$20 i n $1000;
  infile "blah.txt" lrecl = 50000 dsd delimiter = '09'x ;
  if _n_ ge &n then input start end r a i n; 
 run;
```